# Adding Cognito user pool groups using amplify auth update to an existing Cognito resource?

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I already use Cognito in my Amplify CLI app. Can I safely add Cognito user pool groups using `amplify update auth`

```
amplify update auth
Please note that certain attributes may not be overwritten if you choose to use defaults settings
.

You have configured resources that might depend on this Cognito resource.  Updating this Cognito 
resource could have unintended side effects.

Using service: Cognito, provided by: awscloudformation
 What do you want to do? (Use arrow keys)
  Apply default configuration with Social Provider (Federation) 
  Walkthrough all the auth configurations 
❯ Create or update Cognito user pool groups 
  Create or update Admin queries API
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can safely use

```
amplify update auth
```

to add or update groups.

When you are done make sure you run:

```
amplify auth push
```

or

```
amplify push
```

So it applies the changes. It will take a few minutes to run.

You can use

```
amplify init
amplify pull auth
```

to pull all the resources first.